# ArrayList arguments not casting to programmer-specified return values

Tags: java, arraylist

I am fairly new to java, and recently learned how to cast an ArrayList to an object. My current issue when I'm adding variables to an ArrayList is:

> The method set(int, GenericMissile) in the type 
>    ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (int, 
>    float)

I have tried to correct this in many ways, from changing the return value of the setLocationX() method to GenericMissile setLocationX() to casting the global variable to GenericMissile, with no results.

My main question is: How do I go about making the ArrayList in the second class file work with the ArrayList arguments?

To further this question, is there a way to make a class file be casted to any one return value?

Below is my first class, which contains the object I'm running in the second class:

```
public class GenericMissile {
    float currentX;

    float setLocationX() {         
        currentX = (float) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 801);      
        return currentX;
    }
}
```

and in the other class file, I have:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GameManager {
    ArrayList<GenericMissile> allM;

    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        GameManager obj = new GameManager();
        obj.getInfo();
    }

    void getInfo() {     
        allM = new ArrayList<>();
        GenericMissile build = new GenericMissile();

        allm.set(0,build.setLocationX());
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here exactly? You have a List of GenericMissiles but try to add a float to it. That cannot work and i don't think thats your original intention.

Comment: Your ArrayList expects objects of type `GenericMissile` and you try to insert a location instead .... why do you expect this to work?

Comment: Your `ArrayList` is bound to type `GenericMissile`, so it can only accept that. You're trying to insert a `float` here: `allm.set(0,build.setLocationX());`

Answer (score 0):

`GenericMissile#setLocationX()` returns `float` and your ArrayList is bound to type `GenericMissile`, so you're feeding it the wrong type. Did you mean:

```
allM = new ArrayList<>();
GenericMissile build = new GenericMissile();
build.setLocationX();
allM.set(0, build);
```

You could also make `GenericMissile` return itself on `build.setLocationX()` by slightly modifying the `setLocationX`:

```
GenericMissile setLocationX(){
    float setLocationX(){
    currentX = (float) Math.ceil(Math.random()*801);
    return this;
}
```